# geoExt2 application in a CMS (joomla, Wordpress)

Tags: geoext-2, wordpress, joomla, content-management-system

I am working on geoExt2 application but I want to integrate it as "article" in a Joomla (or similar CMS). I don't want special interactions with the CMS just a link from the menu which will serve the geoExt2 gis application.

Have anyone tried this ? 
Are there ways of doing this or CMS & geoEXT2 are mutually exclusive ?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I concluded with a 'dirty' solution of embedding the GeoExt application on  an iframe: in more details:

```
<iframe name="Stack" src="/webgis/index.html" frameborder="1" width="100%" height="850px" scrolling="yes" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' />
```